# GROUP BY Query -why so slow

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to generate a group query on a large table (more than 8 million rows). However I can reduce the need to group all the data by date. I have a view that captures that dates I require and this limits the query bu it's not much better.
Finally I need to join to another table to pick up a field.

I am showing the query, the create on the main table and the query explain below.

Main Query:

```
SELECT  pgi_raw_data.wsp_channel,
        'IOM' AS wsp,
        pgi_raw_data.dated,
        pgi_accounts.`master`,
        pgi_raw_data.event_id,
        pgi_raw_data.breed,
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.handle),
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.payout),
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.rebate),
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.profit)
FROM    pgi_raw_data
        INNER JOIN summary_max
                ON pgi_raw_data.wsp_channel = summary_max.wsp_channel
                        AND pgi_raw_data.dated > summary_max.race_date
        INNER JOIN pgi_accounts
                ON pgi_raw_data.account = pgi_accounts.account
GROUP   BY pgi_raw_data.event_id
ORDER   BY NULL
```

The create table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `pgi_raw_data` (
  `event_id` char(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `wsp_channel` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `dated` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `program` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `track` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `raceno` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `breed` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `pool` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `gross` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `refunds` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `handle` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `payout` decimal(11,4) NOT NULL,
  `rebate` decimal(11,4) NOT NULL,
  `profit` decimal(11,4) NOT NULL,
  `account` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`,`ticket`),
  KEY `idx_account` (`account`),
  KEY `idx_wspchannel` (`wsp_channel`,`dated`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is my view for summary_max:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW 
 `summary_max` AS select `pgi_summary_tbl`.`wsp_channel` AS 
 `wsp_channel`,max(`pgi_summary_tbl`.`race_date`) AS `race_date` 
from `pgi_summary_tbl` group by `pgi_summary_tbl`.`wsp
```

And also the evaluated query:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 6   Using temporary

1   PRIMARY pgi_raw_data    ref idx_account,idx_wspchannel  idx_wspchannel  
7   summary_max.wsp_channel 470690  Using where

1   PRIMARY pgi_accounts    ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 3   gf3data_momutech.pgi_raw_data.account   29  Using index

2   DERIVED pgi_summary_tbl ALL                 42282   Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Any help on indexing would help.

Comment: What are the indexes on `pgi_summary_table`?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need indexes on these fields:

```
pgi_raw_data.wsp_channel,
pgi_raw_data.dated,  
pgi_raw_data.account
pgi_raw_data.event_id,
summary_max.wsp_channel, 
summary_max.race_date, 
pgi_accounts.account
```

The general (not always) rule is anything you are sorting, grouping, filtering or joining on should have an index.

Also: `pgi_summary_tbl.wsp`

Also, why the `order by null`?

Comment: I read ordering by null is efficient as if it's not there the query tries to order it itself which i don't need.

Will add those indexes - event_id is a primary key so not sure that needs one

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to be sure that you have indexes on `pgi_summary_table(wsp_channel, race_date)` and `pgi_accounts(account).`  For this query, you don't need indexes on these columns in the raw data.

MySQL has a tendency to use indexes even when they are not the most efficient path.  I would start by looking at the performance of the "full" query, without the joins:

```
SELECT  pgi_raw_data.wsp_channel,
        'IOM' AS wsp,
        pgi_raw_data.dated,
        -- pgi_accounts.`master`,
        pgi_raw_data.event_id,
        pgi_raw_data.breed,
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.handle),
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.payout),
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.rebate),
        Sum(pgi_raw_data.profit)
FROM    pgi_raw_data
GROUP   BY pgi_raw_data.event_id
```

If this has better performance, you may have a situation where the indexes are working against you.  The specific problem is called "thrashing".  It occurs when a table is too bit to fit into memory.  Often, the fastest way to deal with such a table is to just read the whole thing.  Accessing the table through an index can result in an extra I/O operation for most of the rows.

If this works, then do the joins after the aggregate.  Also, consider getting more memory, so the whole table will fit into memory.

Second, if you have to deal with this type of data, then partitioning the table by date may prove to be a very useful option.  This will allow you to significantly reduce the overhead of reading the large table.  You do have to be sure that the summary table can be read the same way.